# Android App hangs without ANR

Tags: android

Sometimes, when my app receives a new order via push, it hangs. Now the weird thing is that the System UI works fine, the app is unresponsive but the **Application Not Responding** dialog never comes.

I don't know how to debug why it is hanging. Doesn't hang everytime a new order is received, but only rarely.

Any pointers as to why the ANR might not be coming? How to debug?

Comment: Try implementing thread for data operation after receive push

Comment: If  your UI thread, is not get any response for 5 sec ,then is show ANR,So make normally run entirely on a single thread by default the "UI thread" or "main thread"

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the issue as it happens rarely.  Will update when some events do occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should observe the app behavior in the [monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-monitor.html). If the CPU / Memory usage is inordinately high, it could be indicative of either a memory leak or a CPU-intensive task (like an unpurged `TimerTask` or multiple instances of the same `Runnable`) that causes the app to become unresponsive without an ANR.

In case it does turn out to be a memory leak, you could investigate further with [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) or [monkey](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey.html) to further narrow down the exact cause of the leak.

I once came across an animated progress dialog that caused both a huge memory leak **AND** a CPU overload, causing my app to hang *without* throwing an exception.

Comment: So just happened, that the app hung again. Checked the mem usage & sure enough there was a ~70mb spike. Will add LeakCanary & get to the bottom of this mem leak, thanks a lot of pointing me in the right direction