# App is freezed with this messge in logcat "Timeout waiting for IME to handle input event after 2500 ms"

Tags: android, android-edittext, ime

I have edit text with value `"11491992"`
sometimes when try to edit it, app is **freezed** and logcat has this 
`Timeout waiting for IME to handle input event after 2500 ms: com.google.android.inputmethod.latin/com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME`

[Update]

I have some EditText views  and use RxBinding to control enable/disable submit button based on these EditText views

```
        val bag = CompositeDisposable()

        RxTextView.textChanges(edFirstName)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map { it.toString().trim() }
            .subscribe {
                btnSubmit.isEnabled = it.isNotBlank()
                updateRequest.firstName = it
            }.addTo(bag)

        RxTextView.textChanges(edLastName)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map { it.toString().trim() }
            .subscribe {
                btnSubmit.isEnabled = it.isNotBlank()
                updateRequest.lastName = it
            }.addTo(bag)
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you suspect it causes the issue?

Comment: I have added what I do in this screen @MohamedNageh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is OK.

```kotlin
    val bag = CompositeDisposable()

    RxTextView.textChanges(edFirstName)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map { it.toString().trim() }
        .subscribe {
            btnSubmit.isEnabled = it.isNotBlank()
        }.apply { bag.add(this) }

    RxTextView.textChanges(edLastName)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map { it.toString().trim() }
        .subscribe {
            btnSubmit.isEnabled = it.isNotBlank()
        }.apply { bag.add(this) }

    }
```

ANR happens when a long operation is taking place on the main thread. If this thread is **busy**, Android cannot process any further GUI events in the application, and thus throws up an ANR `Application Not Responding` dialog.

From the source code of `android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager` see this function `void finishedInputEvent(int seq, boolean handled, boolean timeout) { ... }`

```java
if (timeout) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Timeout waiting for IME to handle input event after "
            + INPUT_METHOD_NOT_RESPONDING_TIMEOUT + " ms: " + p.mInputMethodId);
} else {
    mH.removeMessages(MSG_TIMEOUT_INPUT_EVENT, p);
}
```

Also always try to handle all timeconsuming operations on any thread other than the main thread.

### Update 1:

see [How an app hanged without an ANR?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41158563/4586030)

- You should use profiler screen.
- LeakCanary if memory leak.

Comment: i did not receive ANR dialoge

Comment: , so we got that problem that there are operation take more time on main thread,
but code use another thread to do its work. So main thread is safe.